# Cypress click and rightclick actions responding when running full test suite

Tags: click, cypress

I have a bunch of Cypress front end tests written in JS for a low code product and the majority of my tests are failing due to Cypress not finding elements that appear after a click/right click action.

This is an example code snippet:

```
 cy.get('#Application_' + name, {timeout: 60000}).rightclick()
 cy.contains('Load Application').should('be.visible').click()
 cy.contains('Yes').should('be.visible').click()
```

I have tried using {force:true} in the click methods, I have tried checking they are visible using shoulds and other plugins such as Cypress-pipe. Any thoughts or directions would be greatly received

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: assert
expected #displayWorkflowAction to be visible
AssertionError
Timed out retrying after 15000ms: Expected to find element: #displayWorkflowAction, but never found it.

Comment: The rightclick operation does not fire.